# How to switch to using google search API in PHP

Tags: php

I want to build a website where you can input some lyrics and find the most relevant songs on youtube automatically. This works pretty well, and I manage to do it by "cheating" with the url when searching on google and then i searched on you tube using their Data API. I would like to perform the google search also by using the Google Search API in PHP but I did not find anything helpful and updated.

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
$input = str_replace(' ', '+', $input);
$input = "azlyrics+".$input;
$link1 = "http://www.google.ro/search?source=hp&ei=Bt4iWprHHYLawALX742gBw&q=";
$link2 = "&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2887.9027.0.11648.29.27.0.0.0.0.206.2011.16j6j1.23.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.18.1346...0j0i10k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j33i160k1.0.2TcuO1Abk1c";
$final = $link1.$input.$link2;
```

Comment: If you want to find a song on YouTube given the lyrics... wouldn't it be better to use YouTube's API rather than Google's? This really does sound like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Comment: Yes. But you need to know what song are you looking for when you use the YouTube API, right? This is why I need to get some results from Google Search

Comment: YouTube has functionality in its API to [**specifically cover searches**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).